# Identity Server 4 for application (Blazor Server Side) configured in iis using reverse proxy redirect url problem

Tags: reverse-proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ids

I am using Identity Server 4 code base to authenticate and authorize my Blazor Server side application deployed on windows server WSL Ubuntu on docker with following detail(IDS 4 application is deployed in same server)

IDS 4 server url https://abc/identityServer/
Blazor application on ubuntu : https://ipaddress of wsl ubuntu:1881

In this case  i used netsh command to transfer server traffic to docker application and Application is working fine if we open port from server and application is available for access. i mean if i open port 1881 on server and access it using https://abc:1881. it is going to IDS 4 project and returning back after authenticaiton.

But customer don't want to access it using port

so i used IIS revers proxy to give public access to the application by URL Rewrite module (ARR). In the reverse proxy i used WSL Ubuntu IP Address and port to forward the request and url is something like https://abc/blazorapplication.

In IDS project i give https://abc/blazorapplication url in to configure client.

Now when request is going to Identity Server 4 project for login and it is redirecting to https://ipaddress of wsl ubuntu:1881 and i dont want any wsl ubuntu information at public side.

Please help how to configure reverse proxy in iis in this case where web site redirection to and from identity server 4 application for authentication.